# Flash gotoAndStop instruction by label name instead of frame number?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have tested with frame number it works, it doesn't with label name. Is it possible ?

In main.as:

```
  public function gotoTab1(target:MouseEvent) { 
    gotoAndStop(1);
  }

  public function gotoTab2(target:MouseEvent) { 
    gotoAndStop("tab2");
  }
```

first works, second doesn't. Second works with

```
  public function gotoTab2(target:MouseEvent) { 
    gotoAndStop(5);
  }
```

of course I give tab2 as label name to the frame at position 5.

no error shows up.
[image]

Comment: could you post some code? usually doing myClip.gotoAndStop('mylabel') works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you labeled the frame with the correct label/name. GotoAndStop works for both frame number and frame label. Check spelling cuz typos are sometimes the culprit! Good luck!

Also, maybe put a stop(); in that frame to ensure flash isn't buzzing through it.

Edit: _root.gotoAndStop("tab2")

Comment: Try a label without numbers and see if that makes a difference. I remember being frustrated once bc I had to relabel some frames, but I don't remember if it involved numbers.

Comment: Ok I See what you're missing. Try "_root.gotoAndStop("tab2");"